# Does/Did the USA support terrorist organization like IS/ISIS or Al-Qaeda with weapons or money?

Tags: united-states, terrorism, cia

In this Free21 [radio interview](https://free21.org/de/content/transcript-kenfm-am-telefon-dr-daniele-ganser-zur-verbindung-zwischen-und-usa), the Swiss historian and controversial author, [Dr. Daniele Ganser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniele_Ganser) claims that USA supports terrorist organizations with money, food and weapons. He claims that the USA does this so that the [Syria opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_opposition) gains power from US support in their conflict with the current Russia-friendly leadership. He also references unnamed Iranian newspapers stating US Army performs weapon drops for [IS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_State_of_Iraq_and_the_Levant).

The hosts of the interview, [Free21](http://free21.org) claim to be a independent journalistic platform, but reading their other articles, in my opinion, stretch their interpretations too far from the sourced facts, so this does not support its credibility.

But it wouldn't be the first time of the CIA using such methods (including assassinating anti-USA leaders), so it would not be completely implausible.

So: Does/Did the USA support terrorist organization like IS/ISIS or Al-Qaeda with weapons/money?

Comment: @AE: If you want to post an answer, please use the answer boxes, so they can be voted upon, edited and accepted. Pseudo-answers in comments are generally removed.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegations_of_CIA_assistance_to_Osama_bin_Laden

Comment: Please limit this question to established facts. We can't provide answers on what the CIA is secretly doing right now...

Comment: @Sklivvz The question says "Does/Did", so it is not limited to what it is doing now, but the answer can also only reference former actions and not only CIA but any USA organizationor the USA themself. In my question I already included an unsourced maybe leaked official document supporting parts of the claim. As I am not that familiar with such documents, I dont fully understand it nor can I say anything about its authenticity. The question could be simply answered by such a document if its authenticity is credible and it states that the USA supported a terror organization with weapons/money.

Comment: Also I saw some interesting comments last night which were deleted today which looked like the beginning of an answer.

Comment: Yep, attempted answers in comments are quite openly deleted without any notice: firstly they are invalid answers and secondly they are invalid comments! :-) Regarding the question: if there is a specific factual claim we can verify, we'll be happy to help. As it stands, it's impossible to disprove the claim, but of course a valid question must allow the possibility that the claim is either true or false.

Comment: Are you skeptical that USA supports specific organizations? (assuming that person actually named them?) Are you skeptical that USA supports SOME unspecified organizations, which a third party (e.g. Al-Assad) can claim to be terrorist? (without USA officially designating them to be so)? Something else?

Comment: Through the comment of @Sklivvz I found out the missing neutrality of the question because it cant be disproved. My skeptic is especially the claim of those named organizations but also why the USA would support terrorist organizations according to western oppinions while beeing officially on war against terrorism.

Comment: In the meantime I found out about the CIAs role in Operation Gladio and similar 3 decades ago in other European countries where they founded terrorist organisations and paid/trained them and used them for terror attacks against civil population in false flag operations to prevent pro russian parties from gaining political power in Europe. But I am interested in the named ones or when similar ones at least after the USA started the war on terror.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cyclone - (CIA) program to arm and finance the Jihad warriors, mujahideen, in Afghanistan from 1979 to 1989,